# odd character in Linux file name

Tags: json, linux, unicode, character-encoding, urlencode

I made a mistake and sent a filename to the server (through cloud API) which contains the scandinavian letter å. I forgot to URL encode it. It shouldn't have been there anyway. If I had spotted it I would have changed it to an a. You can't have scandinavian letters in Linux filenames, can you? Or?

Anyway, what happened was that an odd character turned up in the filename. When I list the file the API shows x\ufffdy.jpg instead of xåy.jpg, the filename I sent. When I list it in the GUI the odd character is displayed as a question mark inside a diamond.

Problem: To delete the file I need to know the exact filename. Alas, since I don't know which character Linux has put there instead of å I can't tell. All attempts fail. It even fails to delete it in the GUI. I managed however to upload an almost empty file with the same filename in the same way so that the file doesn't take up any space on the disk.

Never the less, I would like to have the file deleted. What can I do? To delete I need to send the filename in a json doc, where the character encoding is supposed to be utf8. So much coding and decoding, I am confused.

Comment: I am surprised by \ufffd as å should be \u00e5 but maybe that is just a very similar character.  But you could try with leftctrl+shit+u and then type fffd for typing the character.

Comment: @Lutz \ufffd is actually just a placeholder for a character that doesn't have any unicode. So the character (one or more bytes?) is hidden behind. Maybe I could try all 256 filenames with the byte in question utf8 encoded. But then I assume that there is only one unknown byte in the filename.

Comment: do you have terminal access? I.e. can you ssh into the server? Or how do you access the server?

Comment: Or how do you try to delete the file  - when it is not through the gui?

Comment: @Lutz I have only cloud API access to the file system. That's the problem. I have to send a json doc with the filenames to delete. But the names in there need to be utf8 encoded. I suspect that the filename on disk actually is xåy.jpg (with the ISO-8859-1 byte for å) but if I want to send this filename I need to utf8 encode it yielding a name with 4 chars before .jpg . This name is taken literally by the cloud server and compared with filenames on disk, but there is no match. Note that xåy.jpg isn't valid utf8 code for anything.

Comment: @Lutz My conclusion so far is that it's impossible to delete this file through the cloud API, I would need shell access to the file system.

Comment: if you can encode your json as a bytestream you could try to encode the å either as E5 (229) or C3A5 (195, 165) (UTF8 equivalent - https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl). E5 would be the case  if the filename was actually in ISO-8859-1. Or use an editor that permits writing a file as ASCII with a specific encoding. On Linux e.g. gedit would work.

Comment: @Lutz Thanks for your effort, but it doesn't work. I tried again: First xåy.jpg ISO encoded. Then it reports that this file was deleted: xï¿½y.jpg which means that it has encoded the å I sent with 3 bytes! Then I tried utf8 coding: Then it reports that xÃ¥y.jpg was deleted, which means that it has taken my string literally. But there is no match. It's interesting to note that when I try to delete x\ufffdy.jpg literally, it reports the same file deleted as when I do xåy.jpg but again the file isn't deleted.

Comment: @Lutz My explanation for this is that the å in xåy.jpg isn't recognized as valid utf8 so the server replaces it with \ufffd (3 bytes) before using it. But the file on disk is xåy.jpg . No match. xÃ¥y.jpg is taken literally but again there is no match.

Comment: can you use wildcards? e.g. x[^A-Za-z0-9]y.jpg

Comment: @Lutz I tried but no, it takes the filename literally. It has to match the filename on disk exactly for the file to be deleted. A last ditch try could be some insertion technique, like hackers use, but I don't know what kind of tools the cloud server uses. It it does rm 'xåy.jpg' I could try ';rm x*y.jpg;ls ' as filename but it hardly uses the shell for deletion.